# Create dynamic table using TableView in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin forms and I need to implement a table in Xamarin forms. Requirement is-

Initially table will be empty and has four columns. After feeling form and clicking on submit button, new entry will be added in table. First column is Test, second column is single radio button, third column is again single radio button and forth column is button to delete that row it self.

I need to know which approach will be suitable to implement this requirement. Is it grid layout or tableview or something else.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [Table View use cases](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/#Use_Cases) vs [List View use cases](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/#Use_Cases). Table views are meant for static content. You should really consider a list view for dynamic content. (like adding a row with views) Being new to Xamarin.Forms, you should take the time to read completely through the documentation as (at least for me) it wasn't straightforward. Also, consider a WebView as radio buttons are not going to play nicely across platforms, and your problem would be easily solvable with jQuery.